# Windows 7 not starting up after installing Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-7

Windows 7 was already installed on my laptop.  I installed Ubuntu 12.04 by dual boot partition, but when I start the laptop I get both Ubuntu and Windows on GRUB. When I click on Windows it doesn't start, and it says Windows needs system repairs (it starts repairing and then the computer is automatically turned off). Ubuntu works fine, but I can't view my windows C drive files in Ubuntu (which are saved on the desktop in Windows 7). Can you help me out with this? I don't want to lose my data on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair#Getting_Boot-Repair) to fix it, read carefully the whole article before you start. I recommend that you make a boot-repair cd or usb after you download it from [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home).

For your case, your Windows boot files are probably corrupted, see other options and start from "repair windows boot files"